# The specified table does not exist. [ table_Name] error

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

Hi all I have an small application to add the expense of the day.

For this I am using SQL compact database (CE). While inserting the record into a table name Expenses I am getting error

> The specified table does not exist. [Expenses]

Insertion code is

```
using (var con =new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Acadamy.sdf;
       Persist Security Info=False"))
 {
   con.Open();
   try
    {
     var Cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
     String sqlAddNew = @"INSERT INTO Expenses (name, amount,receipt,details) 
                Values(@name,@amount,@receipt,@details)";
     Cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlAddNew, con);
     Cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
     Cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAmount.Text;
     Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receipt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRecept.Text;
     Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDetails.Text;
     Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
     {
       txtAmount.Text = exception.ToString();
     }
    finally
     {
       if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
     }
   }
}
```

I am not getting why this error occurring. 
Acadamy.sdf structure is as below:

[image]

I am able to retrieve data from another table of the same database. What will be the problem?

Comment: Well presumably the table doesn't exist, whereas the other table you're using does. Check the name of the table very carefully.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Expenses` table in your `Acadamy.sdf` ?

Comment: Yap, see the updated question.

Comment: Look for a copy of your database file in the bin/debug folder without the table.

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes database copy is there but it's having both the tables.

Comment: I don't know your directory structure but are you sure that you are connected to the true database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I get an error about a table that does not exist I use the SQL Server Management Studio and check if the table really is missing or if I just have a typo in my query.

Unfortunately the current version of the Management Studio no longer supports SQL Server Compact Database and you will have to use the 2008 version. You can get it directly from Microsoft: [SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438)

Comment: You can write your SQL command directly inside the Management Studio. Does it give the same error?

Comment: I am not able to check it in Management studio but I checked in LINQPad and it's working.

Comment: What is the problem in the Management studio?